# how to calculate log n(base r ) in O(1) time through c program

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, logging, complexity-theory, big-o

i am unable to find the O(1) way to find log of n with any base

even if you can determine O(1) time way to calculate log of n with base 2 ,it would be thank full.
the  link which i encountered is this http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=10879 (please read the comments on that).
they are saying to calculate the number of zero's in front of a number but how that can be done in O(1) time...
again i took help of this site  whose link is [How To Find The Leading Number Of Zero's In a Number using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234533/how-to-find-the-leading-number-of-zeros-in-a-number-using-c)
but O(1) is big issue for me.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in O(1) for arbitrarily large numbers. You need at least O(log(n)) to look at the binary representation of the number once.

If you put a bound on the value of n (e.g. 64 bits), then *everything* is doable in O(1)! O-notation will not make any real sense in that case.

Comment: In case of a single integer input, you would even say it’s in O(n) where n is the number of binary digits.

Answer (score 1):

If I've undertood correctly, you just want to calculate the log of a number n in base b. In that case, use the `log()` function:

```
log(n)/log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your CPU and your compiler you may be able to get log2 in O(1) for integer numbers. See the answers of this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array) for example. Finding the left most bit of a binary number is the same as log2.